# simple event listener reactjs not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

i am new to react . when i run this code and type somehting in the input nothing appear in the console . what is wrong

```
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
const Copyinput = (e) => {
  console.log("wow");
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type={Text} onchange={Copyinput}></input>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React events are supposed to be [camelCase](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html#:%7E:text=React%20events%20are%20named%20using,handler%2C%20rather%20than%20a%20string.) : `onChange`.

Also, I hope your `Text` is a variable. Otherwise, you can pass it as a string or declare it above your `return`:

`<input type="text" onChange={Copyinput}></input>`

Comment: I was intrigued by that `Text` too and it turns out it's a built-in constructor (`window.Text`).

Comment: Woah. Did not know about it. Can see it in the console, can't find good docs for it though. @RoboRobok any clue?

Comment: If it's an input that value really needs to be stored in state so it can be updated with each `onChange`.

Comment: @TusharShahi I just found this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text/Text

Comment: @Andy True. But wow will still be logged in anycase, which is what the OP wants to achieve for now I guess.

Answer (score 0):

React events are camel case so onchange should be onChange.
Your attribute type should not be in curly braces. It should be string

This will work for you:

```
<input type="text" onChange={Copyinput}></input>
```